# How to add a dart. page from "AppBar" menu "Error URI doesnt exist" but i have made a page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

app bar made ontap materialpageroute made but cannont find a page i have made path LIB/pages/first_page.dart

I was thinking i need some code in the linked page maybe.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX2Os.png)

i tried to add line :

import 'lib/pages/First_Page.dart';

```
   IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Container(
          color: Color(0xFFFF9000),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              DrawerHeader(
                  child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'TCB',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45),
                ),
              )),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.home),
                title: Text(
                  'Page 1',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => First_Page()));
                },
              ),
```

[new pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUxpw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i went with a slighty diffent aproach and did this:

I found this worked my mistake was the named class "addtwonumbers"was the connector thanks all ListTile( leading: Icon(Icons.file_upload), title: Text('Rules'), onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddTwoNumbers()))),

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add `lib` on your path, it will start after the `lib`

```dart
import 'pages/First_Page.dart';
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed the path, but now has unused
Unused import: 'pages/First_Page.dart'.
Try removing the import directive.dartunused_import

Comment: as the lint message says `unused Unused import`, you need to use that widget.

Comment: Thanks MD. yeasin, use that widget in which the main.dart or the new page i have created. Sorry i a bit confussed. I was thinking i need some code in the page im linking too, maybe am i off track there. Or i only need the path to the page on the main.dart?

Comment: sorry, I am little confused about your last comment.  You need to import the place you will use it.

Comment: Sorry Md. Yeasin, I meant 1. the link refernce page as been made called First_page.dart page 
2. The path worked to that First_page.dart page in the main.dart.
now 
3. But when i hover over the import 'pages/First_Page.dart'; get the error:
Unused import: 'pages/First_Page.dart'.
Try removing the import directive.dartunused_import
I was thinking i need to write something maybe a class in the corospoding page Firts_Page.dart to help link it back in HTML you dont need that but maybe dart you do

Comment: in main.dart
import 'pages/First_Page.dart';
 onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => First_Page()));
                },
              ),

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tca/first_page.dart';    //  realated to issue

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: AddTwoNumbers()));
}

class AddTwoNumbers extends StatefulWidget {

                  'Page 1',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => First_Page())); // error was (The method 'First_Page' isn't defined for the type '_AddTwoNumbersState')

Answer (score 0):

you have not import the file.
import 'pages/First_Page.dart'

Comment: Thanks Shubham that fixed the path but new ERROR
Unused import: 'pages/First_Page.dart'.
Try removing the import directive.dartunused_import